# Order of the adjectives

Tags: adjectives

What if there is more than one judgement?

eg.

> comfortable, cheap armchair
>
> bright sunny day

can we say,

> cheap, comfortable armchair
>
> sunny bright day

Can the order be changed?

Comment: As a native speaker, I would say a 'cheap but comfortable armchair' and a 'bright and sunny day', but I don't know how that would be expressed as a rule.

Comment: I think the possible duplicate gives a lot of good information on the general order of categories of adjectives, but doesn't address the questioner's issue of what to do when you have two adjectives in the same category.